Find the equation of the circle that is tangent to 2 lines
Let the lines $(d_1):4x+7y-37=0$ and $(d_2):7x-4y+49=0$, and the points $A(4;3)$ and $N(18;-5)$.
Let $\mathcal C$ the circle that is tangent to $(d_1)$ and $(d_2)$, the intersection between $(d_1)$ and $\mathcal C$ being $A$. Compute the equation of the circle.

Attempts
Equation of $\mathcal C$ is of the form $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=R^2$.
I know that $A$ beling to the circle, that is $(4-a)^2+(3-b)^2=R^2$.
I also know that $(d_2)$ and $\mathcal C$ are tangent, that is, the system
$$\begin{cases}
(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=R^2\\
7x-4y+49=0
\end{cases}$$
has a unique solution
The previous system can be written as the equation
$$\left(\frac{4}{7}y-7-a\right)^2+(y-b)^2=0.$$
So if I develop, I get
$$\frac{65}{49}y^2-2\left(\frac{4}{7}(7+a)+b\right)y+(7+a)^2+b^2=0.$$
Since the equation has a unique solution, $\Delta=0$. But the formula $\Delta $ is a nightmare, so I guess, there are other possibilities. Any idea on how solving this problem ?

the center of the circle must lie in the angle bissector of the two given lines

What is N doing? The other intersection of C and d1? @hellofreinds: C is NOT tangent to d1 and d2 only to d2. so your comment is wrong.

Same question as @trula

@trula but OP states that it's tangent to both?

You are right, a reread the question. and also saying "intersection it says tangent to d1 and d2. so sorry for my comment to hellofriends,

Your equation $(4y/7-7-a)^2+(y-b)^2=0$ is incorrect. Rather it should be $=R^2$.

You can do this. (This kind of works along the line of angle bisector equation, it just breaks it into a bit simpler form)
By distance formula of a point from a line,$\bigg(d=\frac{|ax_1+by_1+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\bigg)$
If centre $C(a,b)$ then
$$R^2=\frac{(4a+7b-37)^2}{4^2+7^2}=\frac{(7a-4b+49)^2}{7^2+4^2}$$
You'll get a relation between $a$ and $b$.
$$(4-a)^2+(3-b)^2=R^2$$
Will allow you 2 more relations.
Hope you'll be able to proceed from here

Mark the centre of the circle $O$. Do you know that two lines with slopes with $m_1$ and $m_2$ orthogonal $\iff m_1m_2=-1$? Since $d_1$ has slope $\frac{-7}{4}$ and $d_2$ has slope $\frac{4}{7}$, it follows they are orthogonal. Let $P$ be the intersection of $d_1$ and $d_2$. Solving the two equations of $d_1$ and $d_2$ simultaneously gives $P:(-3,7)$. Since $\overline{PA}=\sqrt{65}$, it follows that in $\Delta OAP$, $\tan \angle OPA = \tan \frac{\pi}4 = \frac{r}{\overline{PA}}=1$ thereby giving $r=\sqrt{65}$.
Using the same idea of orthogonality, it follows the line $L$ joining $O$ and $A$ has slope $4/7$ since it is orthogonal to $d_1$ and since $(4,3)\in L$ it follows $L: 4y=7x-16$. But since $(a,b) \in L$ we have $b=7a/4-4$.
As you already figured, $(4-a)^2+(3-b)^2=r^2$ and put in all the values to get an equation in $a$: $$(4-a)^2+(7-7a/4)^2=65$$ $$a(a-8)=0$$
Solving this quadratic is straightforward giving $(a,b): (0,-4)\lor (8,10)$.
So there are two such circles possible, which are..?

Note that two straight lines here are perpendicular (by checking their slopes), write their intersection as $B$.
On the other hand, if we write $O$ as the center of $\mathcal{C}$, then by the property that tangent perpendicular radius, $OA$ is perpendicular to $d_1$. Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ touches $d_2$ at $D$, then similarly we have $OD\perp BD$. This gives an interesting idea, is $O,A,B,D$ four points will form a square (they are rectangle by the perpendicular nature, and $OA=OD$, so it is a square)
Now, you have the coordinates of $B$ and $A$, and your job is to find such square, which should not be tough. (See the spoiler below in case you have no idea)

By computation $B=(3,-7)$. The coordinates of $O$ can be obtained by rotating $B$ about $A$ for $90^\circ$ clockwise or anticlockwise, correspondingly are $(8,10)$ and $(0,-4)$. Moreover, the radius is just $AB=\sqrt{7^2+4^2}$. So the equation are $$(x-8)^2+(y-10)^2=65\quad\text{and}\quad x^2+(y+4)^2=65$$


When solving such questions, always make a drawing!
In this case, the drawing clearly shows you how the solutionS look like:


As has been stated, $d_1$ and $d_2$ are perpendicular to one another. Find where they intersect. Use this point, along with a slope that is in between the slopes of $d_1$ and $d_2$, to find the equation of a new line, call it $d_3$. Basically, $d_3$ will share the intersection point between $d_1$ and $d_2$, be at a $45^\circ$ to both $d_1$ and $d_2$, and run through the center of $\textit C $. At this point, you can use $A(4,3)$ to find the equation of yet another line, call it $d_4$, that will be perpendicular to $d_1$ and also run through the center of $\textit C$. With all this, you can find its center and radius.
